# Does this poster convey femininity and multiculturalism?

Tags: color, typography, critique, alignment

This poster I made for our multicultural womens evening. It should represent femininity, multi-cultural and be an eye-catcher to get many women to our event.

I know the colors are commonly used for multi-cultural identity, but it does not matter, because the most important that it is seen and recognized!

And please let me know if I have made some bad mistakes on the design.

[image]

Edit:

Thanks so much, here a edited version:
[image]

I'll answer in the comments!

Comment: Says translate/Finnish: Women's multi-cultural meeting - Sepa center Kyllikki the street 1 - 12/06/2014 Saturday - at 14-16 - the food world - coffee and cake - Flea Market - children activities - Winter Tatars point - Organised by: -About Lisa:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Really nice design! I think you definitely got the vibe right.

Couple of things to consider:

- The email at the bottom, because the text is in the same font, it makes it a little difficult to read. If you made the first word bold, for example, that would separate it a little more.
- I find the alignment of the date and the word Lauantai a little confusing. Maybe because of the colors, I would prefer to see a block of pink on the top and then the black grouped on the bottom.
- I also find the 6 on the date a little too close to the blue drop, which works better for the rest of the text because it's in black.

Since you are going to be printing this, make sure your border gets printed (make it at least 10mm wide).

Comment: I'll second the comment about the line at the bottom (the email and whatever the other one on the left is). I would suggest a simple sans serif for both those phrases, because they are (I think) contact information, and your lovely display font is hard to read at that size.

Comment: I third the motion! Aside from that, nice design!

Comment: Another suggestion would be to make the subhead quite a bit smaller, perhaps half the current size, to give more contrast. It will help the visual impact.

Comment: maybe a second font might help separate the heading - bit difficult not reading Finnish, be nice to see how you use the elements to produce different channel advertising, supporting material, event collateral - but definitely a fairly strong start

Comment: Thanks, I changed the font below to Times New Roman. Would a serif font be better for the overall visual effect, since the display font is serif too?

Comment: @AlanGilbertson do you mean the "monikulttuurinen tapaaminen"? I tried to make it smaller, but the first heading seemed too big then. Or did you mean another part of the heading?

Comment: @Owl The redesign is definitely improved. I suggested a sans serif for the contact information because Times still has serifs and it doesn't contrast enough to my eye. It looks almost-sort-of like a mistake. A clean Helvetica would be a complete contrast and a break with the intricate curlicues of the display font.

Comment: Ok thanks @LaurenIpsum I have no license for Helvetica, so I took Liberation Sans for it, it is really better. Thank you!